# Why do I get error C2440 when I try to compile XPCOM code?

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, gecko

I need to create a Firefox addon that calls C++ code. I did some research and found this tutorial to get me started: http://briankrausz.com/building-a-c-xpcom-component-in-windows/

I followed all the steps but got stuck in the part where I need to compile the code using VS. I'm using VS 2005.

To be more specific, I have a project that contains 2 header files (`IMyComponent.h` & `MyComponent.h`) as well 2 cpp files (`MyComponent.cpp` & `MyComponentModule.cpp`).

Each cpp file is configured to compile with no CLR support and without precompiled headers.

However, when I attempt to compile, I get 3 C2440 error messages that correspond to the following lines of code:

```
//MyComponentModule.cpp

#include "nsIGenericFactory.h"
#include "MyComponent.h"

NS_GENERIC_FACTORY_CONSTRUCTOR(MyComponent)

static nsModuleComponentInfo components[] =
{
    {
      MY_COMPONENT_CLASSNAME,
      MY_COMPONENT_CID,          //'initializing': cannot convert from const char[37]    to PRUint32
      MY_COMPONENT_CONTRACTID, //'initializing': cannot convert from const char[39] to    PRUint16
      MyComponentConstructor, //'initializing': cannot convert from nsresult (__stdcall *)(nsISupports *, const nsIID &, void **) to PRUint16
   }
};

NS_IMPL_NSGETMODULE("MyComponentsModule", components)
```

In the correspond header file I have the following code:

```
//MyComponent.h

#ifndef _MY_COMPONENT_H_
#define _MY_COMPONENT_H_

#include "IMyComponent.h"

#define MY_COMPONENT_CONTRACTID "@example.com/XPCOMSample/MyComponent;1"
#define MY_COMPONENT_CLASSNAME "A Simple XPCOM Sample"
#define MY_COMPONENT_CID "4c6f45e0-6366-4c69-Ab68-bb3c75cdada3"

class MyComponent : public IMyComponent
{
public:
 NS_DECL_ISUPPORTS
 NS_DECL_IMYCOMPONENT

 MyComponent();

private:
  ~MyComponent();

protected:
  /* additional members */
};

#endif //_MY_COMPONENT_H_
```

All the other code was generated using the xpidl.exe tool included with the Gecko SDK.

Can someone please give some hints?

PS: Here is the nsModuleComponentInfo:

```
 struct nsModuleComponentInfo {
 const char*                                 mDescription;
 nsCID                                       mCID;
 const char*                                 mContractID;
 NSConstructorProcPtr                        mConstructor;
 NSRegisterSelfProcPtr                       mRegisterSelfProc;
 NSUnregisterSelfProcPtr                     mUnregisterSelfProc;
 NSFactoryDestructorProcPtr                  mFactoryDestructor;
 NSGetInterfacesProcPtr                      mGetInterfacesProc;
 NSGetLanguageHelperProcPtr                  mGetLanguageHelperProc;
 nsIClassInfo **                             mClassInfoGlobal;
 PRUint32                                    mFlags;
 };
```

Comment: Can you also post the declaration of `nsModuleComponentInfo`?

Comment: You probably need someway to cast the data types. Sorry, I'm not more helpful for I don't know about the firefox technique but that is an error code that I'm sure you can see if self explanatory. It can't convert one datatype to the other. A `char[x]` is really an array of 1 byte(on most systems) `int`s. So it could possibly be that it's out of it's capability.?? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z(v=vs.80).aspx) is always helpful as well!

Comment: When you declare `components` it looks like you are missing a few pieces of data that should be at the beginning of the structure before `MY_COMPONENT_CLASSNAME`. In fact there are 3 member variables before  the Contract ID.

Comment: Chris, please see the original post. i have added the code you requested.

Comment: Just a note: you would be better off using [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) if possible (add your own library to the extension and call its exported functions). An XPCOM component needs to be recompiled for each Firefox release which is every 6 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you are trying to pass in a `char *` instead of the required type.  This page:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_XPCOM_components_to_Mozilla_build_system

at least mentions how to deal with the CID param:

```
{ "Friendly class description for people to read",
 YOUR_CLASS_CID,
 YOUR_CLASS_CONTRACTID,
 nsYourConcreteClassNameConstructor }
```

and

```
/* 2d96b3d0-c051-11d1-a827-0040959a28c9 */
#define NS_WINDOW_CID \
{ 0x2d96b3d0, 0xc051, 0x11d1, \
{0xa8, 0x27, 0x00, 0x40, 0x95, 0x9a, 0x28, 0xc9}}
```

Comment: I set MY_COMPONENT_CID to a value formatted like the one above and the code now compiles. Thanks